# html5lib with lxml treebuilder doesn't parse namespaces correctly

Tags: python, lxml, html5lib

I'm trying to parse some HTML content with `html5lib` using the `lxml` treebuilder. Note: I'm using the `requests` library to grab the content and the content is HTML5 (tried with XHTML - same result).

When I simply output the HTML source, it looks alright:

```
response = requests.get(url)
return response.text
```

returns

```
<html xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/ns/foo">
```

But when I'm actually parsing it with the html5lib, something odd happens:

```
tree = html5lib.parse(response.text, treebuilder = 'lxml', namespaceHTMLElements = True)
html = tree.getroot()
return lxml.etree.tostring(html, pretty_print = False)
```

returns

```
<html:html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlnsU0003Afoo="http://www.example.com/ns/foo">
```

Note the `xmlnsU0003Afoo` thing.

Also, the `html.nsmap` dict does not contain the `foo` namespace, only `html`.

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on and how I could fix this?

**Later edit:**

It seems that this is expected behavior:

> If the XML API being used restricts the allowable characters in the local names of elements and attributes, then the tool may map all element and attribute local names [...] to a set of names that are allowed, by replacing any character that isn't supported with the uppercase letter U and the six digits of the character's Unicode code [...]
>   - [Coercing an HTML DOM into an infoset](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#coercing-an-html-dom-into-an-infoset)

Comment: can you provide an example url?

Comment: Currently I'm using sample data that I created on my local webserver. But it should be obvious from the example output. It's just an HTML document with custom namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

- HTML5 doesn't seem to support xmlns attributes. Quoting [section 1.6 of the latest HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml): "...namespaces cannot be represented using the HTML syntax, but they are supported in the DOM and in the XHTML syntax." I see you tried with XHTML as well, but you're currently using HTML5, so there could be an issue there. `U+003A` is the Unicode for colon, so somehow the `xmlns` is being noted but flubbed.
- There is [an open issue with custom namespace elements](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/issues/detail?id=131&q=xmlns&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Port) for at least the PHP version.
- I don't understand the role of `html5lib` here. Why not just use `lxml` directly:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(resp_text)
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

That seems to do what you want, without `html5lib` and without the goofy `xmlnsU0003Afoo` error. With the test HTML I used, I got the right output (follows), and `tree.nsmap` contained an entry for `'foo'`.

```html
<html xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/ns/foo">
    <head>
        <title>yo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>test</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use pure `html5lib`, you can just use the included `simpletree`:

```py
tree = html5lib.parse(resp_text, namespaceHTMLElements=True)
print tree.toxml()
```

While this doesn't muck up the `xmlns` attribute, `simpletree` unfortunately lacks the more powerful `ElementTree` functions like `xpath()`.

Comment: 1. The problem here is not whether HTML5 supports `xmlns` or not. The problem is the library doesn't seem to parse the attribute correctly, regardless of it's meaning, i.e. I can't even do: `html.attrib['xmlns:foo']` but insead I have to do: `html.attrib['xmlnsU0003Afoo']` (well, since I have to act like I don't know the prefix, I'll have to loop over each attribute and see if it starts with `xmlnsU0003A`) I find it strange, really.

Comment: 2. I'm using html5lib for 2 reasons: one of them is that currently I'm just fooling around, learning the Python language and other cool stuff. The second one is eventually the app I'm building has to be able to work with real pages on the web and I want it to see them the way browsers see them (and, as a result, the way developers see them, that's the whole point).

Comment: 3. I did see that thread in their issues list regarding the PHP port. That and a chat log are the only things I could find (the chat log was pointless, someone was saying that the `html5lib` is broken in regard to namespaces). I thought I'd ask people on SO before filing an issue, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: But anyway, my interest is to move forward with the project so I'll switch to the HTML parser included in `lxml` for now. I will file an issue tomorrow morning on the `html5lib` website and see what they are saying. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I too would prefer that `html5lib` behave as you expected. OTOH,  parsers have a long history of having unexpected results on unexpected or mal-formed input. Since `xmlns` attributes aren't legal in HTML5, that could be part of the problem. GIGO. I hope that's the issue, because recoding the attribute as `xmlnsU0003Afoo` is a horrible goof otherwise! Well, it's a horrible goof in any case, but...

Comment: As far as I know, the colon character ":" should be accepted as a valid character in an attribute name, irrespective of the namespace support. If it's not a valid character, then why is it that the `xmlns:html` attribute is not only recognized as an attribute but actually interpreted as a namespace declaration? It would be a shame to find out it is, in fact, hardcoded `if attr == 'xmlns:html'` :) Meanwhile, I filed an issue and hopefully I'll get an answer.

Comment: Apparently that's expected behavior: "If the XML API being used restricts the allowable characters in the local names of elements and attributes, then the tool may map all element and attribute local names [...] to a set of names that are allowed, by replacing any character that isn't supported with the uppercase letter U and the six digits of the character's Unicode code [...]" See [Coercing an HTML DOM into an infoset](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#coercing-an-html-dom-into-an-infoset)

Comment: If you're willing to give up `xpath()` and such, pure `html5lib` will parse as you desire into a `simpletree`. (See code added to end of previous answer.)

Comment: I thought about using the default treebuilder but I need a way to move around quickly. I'm not sure `simpletree` is even usable in the real world. I'll probably play with it someday, but until then I'll stick to `lxml`. Actually, before starting this, I was looking for `ElementTree` (I knew about it while doing some research a while ago and found it neat) and I was pleasantly surprised to find that `lxml.etree` has a similar API.

Comment: I totally understand. ElementTree is very low-level, even in the best case. `lxml`'s ability to do easy `xpath` searches helps greatly, but for document processing (like HTML) is still **TERRIBLE** compared to something like Perl's [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.41/Twig.pm).

Comment: Though great for text processing, Perl is not really an option. Not for me. I fooled around with it some time ago and couldn't understand my own code the day after. It takes a huge amount of time and energy to become a monk, but I've been working in the advertising industry for the past 6 years and the deadline is always "yesterday" so I have to move as quickly as possible. I'm sure, though, there's a one-liner in Perl for delivering last week. Perl is so fast you can even travel back in time and fix errors before they occur :D Can't have them all!